# wsHttpBinding reverted back to basic httpBinding

Tags: wcf

I have created a service with wsHttpBinding but every time i download the service, it creates the basichttpbinding in client's config. Any ideas why?
thansk

```
<system.serviceModel>
    <serviceHostingEnvironment/>
    <bindings>

      <wsHttpBinding>
        <binding name="WSHttpBinding" sendTimeout="00:10:00" receiveTimeout="00:59:00" bypassProxyOnLocal="false"
         transactionFlow="false" hostNameComparisonMode="StrongWildcard"
         maxBufferPoolSize="50000000" maxReceivedMessageSize="50000000"
         messageEncoding="Mtom" textEncoding="utf-8" useDefaultWebProxy="true"
         allowCookies="false">
          <readerQuotas maxDepth="32" maxStringContentLength="50000000"
           maxArrayLength="50000000" maxBytesPerRead="4096" maxNameTableCharCount="2147483647" />
          <reliableSession inactivityTimeout="00:59:00" />
          <security mode="Message">
            <!--<transport clientCredentialType="Windows" proxyCredentialType="None"
       realm="" />-->
            <message clientCredentialType="UserName" negotiateServiceCredential="true"
             algorithmSuite="Default" establishSecurityContext="true" />
          </security>
        </binding>
      </wsHttpBinding>
    </bindings>

    <services>
      <service behaviorConfiguration="AdviserPayServiceBehaviour" name="AdviserPay.Services.FirstService.FirstService">
        <endpoint binding="wsHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="WSHttpBinding" contract="AdviserPay.Services.FirstService.IFirstService" />
        <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexHttpBinding" contract="IMetadataExchange" />
      </service>
    </services>

    <behaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior name="AdviserPayServiceBehaviour">
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" />
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="false" />
          <serviceAuthorization principalPermissionMode="None" impersonateCallerForAllOperations="false" />
          <serviceCredentials>
            <userNameAuthentication userNamePasswordValidationMode="Custom"
              membershipProviderName="AdviserPayCustomMembershipProvider" />
          </serviceCredentials>
          <serviceSecurityAudit auditLogLocation="Application" suppressAuditFailure="false"
            serviceAuthorizationAuditLevel="None" messageAuthenticationAuditLevel="SuccessOrFailure" />
          <serviceThrottling maxConcurrentCalls="100" maxConcurrentSessions="100" />
        </behavior>
        <behavior name="">
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" />
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="false" />
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
  </system.serviceModel>
```

Comment: yes.. that's starting with <system.serviceModel> and ending with </system.serviceModel>.. ??

Comment: Are you sure that service is working and using your configuration? I'm suspicious that it doesn't because at the moment you set up message security but you didn't configured any certificate for it. What do you see when you open services's WSDL in the browser? Are there security assertions?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's likely that the service name in the .svc markup file does not match the name specified in web.config.

When WCF starts your service, the framework checks the service name in the .svc file, then looks in web.config for a configuration matching that name.  If none is found, it uses the default configuration - BasicHttpBinding.

To fix your problem:

1. Right click on FirstService.svc
2. Click 'View Markup'
3. Ensure that the Service attribute matches the service name attribute in web.config.

Comment: I'm pretty certain that the configuration in web.config is not being loaded - can you post the contents of FirstService.svc?

Comment: Thanks for this. I had exactly the same problem and indeed it was a mismatch of service name between svc file and web.config

Answer (score 1):

I have the same problem, but my service works. In my case I expose two bindings both basichttp and wshttp. I have a test web site that was created new on the .net 3.5. when it gets the services references it brings down both bindings i comment out the basic endpoint. 
And it all works.

However,
the real consumer is a website that was orignally created in .net 2.0 and has be since upgraded to 4.0. So i do the same process as before, comment out the basicHttp endpoint. but what happens is i get exception when calling the service and it is expecting to send and receive http, server refuses the connection in this test.

This has to be something with the site being upgraded to 4.0 and not originally created in 3.5 or higher. I can tell this was an upgrade situation because the properties folder that is normally present doesn't exist on the real service consumer site.

There has got to be a flag/setting to turn on but i am not sure what.